# Request data from controller, to route, to view

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have a method in my HomeController that requires some arguments to work.

```
public function mcQuery($ip, $port){
    $Query = new MinecraftQuery();
     try
        {
            $Query->Connect( $ip, $port );

            return $Query;
        }
        catch( MinecraftQueryException $e )
        {
            return false;
        }
}
```

This method is comes with a class that's [from this GitHub](https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Minecraft-Query).

I' need to request this method from a route...

```
Route::post('/servers', function(){
         $ip = Input::get('ip');
         $port = Input::get('port');
        // ... Get info from mcQuery($ip, $port);
         return $info; 
});
```

Which sends the data to my ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/servers',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {ip: serverIp, port: serverPort},
})
.done(function(data) {
    console.log("success" + data);
})
```

Problem is, I have no idea to call that method (with the arguments) in my route file to get the data. What should I do? I need to past the serverIp and serverPort to mcQuery and return it back.

Comment: You're using a lambda function as your route method. Maybe you should change this to a controller and add your code there. For example you could add a `servers` method in the `HomeController` and call the `mcQuery` there. If you're going to use the data into a ajax call, you could probably want to code it in json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
Route::post('/servers', function(){
    $ip = Input::get('ip');
    $port = Input::get('port');

    $home = App::make('HomeController');
    $info = $home->mcQuery($ip, $port);
    return $info;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping, again. I really appreciate it. Sadly I am getting a 500 (Internal Server Error) in the console.

Comment: Does your `HomeController` has same name I gave ?

Comment: Make sure you did this.

Comment: Do you mean is my HomeController is called HomeController? Yes it is.

Comment: make sure your `mcQuery` method in `HomeController` is doing the right thing.

Comment: To debug, try `dd()` after each line at a time for example, `$home = App::make('HomeController');dd($home)` and make sure you got `HomeController`instance then test next line.

Comment: what dd returns object(HomeController)#123 (3) {
  ["layout":protected]=>
  string(14) "layouts.master"
  ["beforeFilters":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["afterFilters":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }